# minPointLength is not working for horizontal Trellis bar charts in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to show the zero value in the trellis horizontal bar charts. I have tried using the **minPointLength** to show the zero value. but its not working, and I have tested for another stocked vertical charts its working, but the issue with  horizontal charts only. working example for vertical charts [vertical charts](http://jsfiddle.net/dp0c30xv/)

code i have tried:

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
          minPointLength: 3
          }
    },
```

please find the horizontal charts [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tddvf4p1/).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your `plotOptions` refer to the `column` type of the series, but the ones that you use are `bar` series. If you change the code from your question to:

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    minPointLength: 8
  }
},
```

everything seems to work fine.

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/c4tbpqLe/